# How can I obtain a complete list of the kinds of atomic expressions in the Wolfram Language using only the language itself?

Tags: expression-manipulation, symbols, expression-form

I mean, Wolfram is a language--it's words are infinitely combinable. According to answers to [my last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202269/how-can-i-ask-the-wolfram-language-to-tell-me-if-a-hypothetical-expression-with), the only way I can find out if an expression is atomic is actually use the expression.

But I can hardly test an infinity of expressions to find all the ones that are atoms and all the ones that are not. And I'm not interested in complete list of all expressions that are atomic. I just want a list of the kinds of atoms. Like, I know integers are atomic, and strings too. But what else?

Comment: Would be a dupe of an old question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46850/61597 if the answer wasn't a bit out of date.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue) to find out what symbols can be atomic:

```
EntityValue[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"], "CanonicalName"]
```

> {"AggregationLayer", "Association", "Audio", "BasicRecurrentLayer", 
>   "BatchNormalizationLayer", "BooleanFunction", "BoundaryMeshRegion", 
>   "ByteArray", "CatenateLayer", "ColorProfileData", "Complex", 
>   "ConstantArrayLayer", "ConstantPlusLayer", "ConstantTimesLayer", 
>   "ContrastiveLossLayer", "ConvolutionLayer", "CrossEntropyLossLayer", 
>   "Dataset", "DeconvolutionLayer", "Dispatch", "DotLayer", "DropoutLayer", 
>   "ElementwiseLayer", "EmbeddingLayer", "FlattenLayer", "GatedRecurrentLayer", 
>   "Graph", "Image", "Image3D", "ImageAugmentationLayer", "Integer", 
>   "LinearLayer", "LocalResponseNormalizationLayer", "LongShortTermMemoryLayer", 
>   "MeanAbsoluteLossLayer", "MeanSquaredLossLayer", "MeshRegion", "NetChain", 
>   "NetDecoder", "NetEncoder", "NetEvaluationMode", "NetExtract", 
>   "NetFoldOperator", "NetGraph", "NetInitialize", "NetMapOperator", "NetModel", 
>   "NetNestOperator", "NetPairEmbeddingOperator", "NetPort", "NetPortGradient", 
>   "NetReplacePart", "PaddingLayer", "PartLayer", "PoolingLayer", "Rational", 
>   "RawData", "Real", "ReplicateLayer", "ReshapeLayer", "ResizeLayer", 
>   "SequenceLastLayer", "SequenceMostLayer", "SequenceRestLayer", 
>   "SequenceReverseLayer", "SoftmaxLayer", "SparseArray", 
>   "SpatialTransformationLayer", "String", "StructuredArray", "SummationLayer", 
>   "ThreadingLayer", "TotalLayer", "TransposeLayer", "UnitVectorLayer"}

Comment: Wow. That's a lot of atoms.

Thank you, this is what I needed!