# AtomQ[Counts[{a, c, d, b, a, c, b}]] gives True. Why?

Tags: core-language

I don’t understand this:

```
In[]:  AtomQ[Counts[{a, c, d, b, a, c, b}]]     
Out[]:  True
```

It looks like an expression. 
Does this have to do with the realization of the expression?

Dani

Comment: similar: [Evaluated vs. unevaluated Association](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204254/142)

Comment: "Everything is an expression" is an ideal not a contract. Some things are treated as atomic objects. `Association` is one of those.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the earliest versions of *Mathematica*, atoms were largely restricted to simple objects which appeared as the leaves within basic [head-plus-elements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicObjects.html) expressions.  Such atoms included symbols and strings, along with integer, real, rational and complex numbers.  These early atoms had no internal structure beyond their intrinsic value, and hence no expression subparts.

But as the language evolved, it became clear that some types of functionality could not be implemented in an efficient manner using only head-plus-elements.  The `Association` returned by the `Counts[...]` expression in the question is one such example.

Initially, the solution was to to introduce a specialized object type which was almost indistiguishable from a head-plus-elements expression.  An example of this is the packed array (see [3496](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/142)).

But increasingly the solution has been to introduce new atomic types.  Examples include `Graph`, `SparseArray` and (as observed in the question) `Association`.  The list of atomic types grows with each release and is now quite long (see [46850](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46850/142) and [202274](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202274/142)).

```
EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"] // EntityList // Length
(* 75 *)
```

That list is not necessarily complete since at time of writing `Symbol` is missing from the list.

These new atoms, being atoms, have no subparts in the conventional sense of a symbolic expression.  Yet they often had complex internal structure, with many internal properties that may or may not be accessible from the outside.  This complex-internals-yet-no-subparts dichotomy can be a source of confusion.

The input forms of some atomic types *look* like they are a normal head-plus-elements expression, but if you try to access their subparts you will get different results than their appearance would imply.  For example `Graph` (see [4301833](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4301833/211232)):

```
$g = Graph[{1 -> 2}];

AtomQ[$g]
(* True *)

$g // InputForm

(* Graph[{1, 2}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2]}] *)

$g[[1]]
  (* Part::partd: Part specification Graph[...][[1]] is longer than depth of object. *)
```

... or `Association` which simulates part access but only to a certain extent (see [204254](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204254/142)):

```
$a = <| "a" -> 1 |>;

AtomQ[$a]
(* True *)

$a // FullForm
(* Association[Rule["a",1]] *)

$a[[1]]
(* 1, we might have expected Rule["a",1] *)

$a[[1, 1]]
(* Part::partd: Part specification <|a->1|>[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object.
   We might have expected "a" *)
```

Similarly, `SparseArray` part access does not conform to its apparent input form:

```
$sa = SparseArray[{1 -> 10, 3 -> 20}, 500, 999];

AtomQ[$sa]
(* True *)

$sa // InputForm
(* SparseArray[Automatic, {500}, 999, {1, {{0, 2}, {{1}, {3}}}, {10, 20}}] *)

$sa[[3]]
(* 20, might have expected 999 as it is the third part of the input form *)
```

It is increasingly common for the latest atomic additions to the language to have a graphical display form, the so-called information "raft":

```
$sa
```

[image: SparseArray screenshot]

To help overcome their opaque nature, atomic types often have specialized operations that can access their otherwise inaccessible internal structures:

```
VertexList[Graph[{"a" -> "b"}]]
(* {"a", "b"} *)

Keys[<|"a" -> 1|>]
(* {"a"} *)

SparseArray[{1 -> 10, 3 -> 20}, 500, 999]["Background"]
(* 999 *)
```

To add to the confusion, most of the atomic types are constructed by using basic head-plus-elements expressions that resemble their input forms.  Their *constructors* are not atomic, but their apparently identical *input forms* are atomic:

```
AtomQ[<|"a"->1|> // Unevaluated] (* False *)
AtomQ[<|"a"->1|>] (* True *)

AtomQ[Graph[{1->2}] // Unevaluated] (* False *)
AtomQ[Graph[{1->2}]] (* True *)

AtomQ[SparseArray[{1->10, 2->20}] // Unevaluated] (* False *)
AtomQ[SparseArray[{1->10, 2->20}]] (* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ("Atoms are also symbolic expressions, but they are special in that they are symbolic expressions that don’t have any parts.")